# Setting textview text in code

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

I'm trying to change my textview called MyText to something else, but when I try I get the error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2071)

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
    TextView texting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyText);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        texting.setText("Test");

};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how your code should look like:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        // If you're not using this view anywhere, you don't have to declare it globally. Use only a local variables
        TextView texting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyText);
        texting.setText("Test");

    };
}
```

You should ALWAYS initialize your views after you have your root layout. In this case, right after you did setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen); This scenario applies to Activites.

In case you use a fragment you should do this right after you inflated your root layout in the onCreateView method. Something like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    // THIS is where you start initializing your views
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was doing my head in.

Answer (score 1):

The TextView is not available until after `setContentView` is called. So, `findViewById` will return null when `MainScreen` is instantiated.  The solution is to move the `findViewById` call to the `onCreate` method as follows:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
    TextView texting;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        texting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyText);

        texting.setText("Test");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
    TextView texting;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        texting = = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyText);
        texting.setText("Test");

    };
}
```

You have to initialize your TextView object inside your onCreate method.